# How to hide tab bars and show full tableview on screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, resize, uitabbarcontroller

In my app's implementation, I have a tabbar controller with 5 different tabs.

After I hide my tab bar via the following code

```
- (void)hideTabBar
{
    for(UIView *view in self.tabController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

I still see the bottom portion of my tableview obscured by a white rectangular section (previously occupied by visible tabbar)

For example, before I hide the tab bar

[image]

After I hide the tab bar, the tableview still does not completely show on the screen, the bottom section is still occupied by a white rectangular space (previously occupied by the tab bar

[image]

As mentioned above, how can I hide the tabbar and ensure that the whole tableview is displayed on my screen?

Comment: Please stop putting tags in your titles. It wastes valuable space (and is redundant).

Comment: see
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller) for solution to this problem

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28787363/667586

Answer (score 0):

myViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;