# Transparent tabbar with tableView under

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a tabbar with a transparent background. One of the tabbar items load a view with a UITableView in it. Is it possible to have that tableview to go "under" the tabbar? That is, have the tableview to fill the whole screen size.

Thanks

Comment: I have had no luck with this so far, so I ended up hiding the built-in tab bar and faking tabs with a custom `UIView` with buttons. Still, I'm curious if there is a less hacky way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you push a viewController on a navigation stack, you can use this:

```
[controller setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
```

Or look at this topic for manual hiding/showing it

[How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller)