# Custom UITabBar for minimise and restore purpose

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use a custom UITabBar in my iOS app, with a button just above it to hide/minimise and show/restore it. I used a custom Tab bar from [here](http://blog.holler.com/custom-iphone-tab-bar-2011-10) but i couldnt get it to woek. I added a button in `ViewDidLoad` of a UINavigationController subclass and added a target selector to hide/show the tab bar in all views but i want that selector to be used everywhere in the app. Is such a Tab bar even possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved through this [link][1]
...works great :)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
UIview *tabView=[UIview alloc]initwitFrame:CGRectMake(0,260,320,60)];

UIButton *btn=[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,20)];
[btn setTitle:@"SHOW/HIDE"];
you can add Target to your btn here...
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showNHide:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tabView addSubView:btn];
[youTabbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,320,40)];
[tabView addSubView:yourTabbar];
```

then add whole view into your view
   [ self.view addSubView:tabView];

then in your showNHide method you can code for Animation of that...
This is not perfect answer but i hope this will give you some idea