# Tab bar is hiding in after switching back

Tags: ios5, xcode4, uitabbar

I've Tab bar application and i will load the other view controller by navigation controller when i come back the tab bar is hiding i searched and i used

```
for(UIView *view in self.window.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBarItem class]])
        {
            if(view.hidden){

                view.hidden = NO;
                break;
            }
            view.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

but the problem remains same can any one know the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of result you want to achieve but perhaps you can check previous question to hide and display TabBar

[How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller)

If it doesn't work you can try to paste the code you are using to declare the TabBar