# Animating the tab bar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm following this [guide](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/24/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-game-sprite/) to create some animations to my app and thought about writing a very light not distracting animation to my tab bar. I've searched apple guidelines but didn't saw anything against it, yet, I don't think I've ever seen an app doing something similar. Is that because it's not allowed or is there another reason I'm missing?
Any one knows an app that does something similar?

Comment: What are you planning to do? I have a simple slide in/out animation for the tab bar in one of my apps and had no problems getting it into the App Store.

Comment: I was thinking about a fade in, fade out when the center button is pushed to get more screen real estate. I'd love to see the functionality of your tab bar.

Comment: The code I'm using is http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272497/725594

Comment: If your app is in the appstore that answers my question. You can write it as an answer so I'll be able to accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a simple slide in/out effect for the tab bar in my App.

No problems in the review.

The code I'm using is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272497/725594

Comment: I tried out your code that works great but I'm using a raised center button in my tabbar and when I hide the tab bar the center button (image) is smeared over the screen and doesn't disappear. Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: You could try editing both your show and hide function.         if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
should be if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])

Comment: The center image is still smeared across the screen. Any other idea?