# Unable to make tabbar visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9

I am having an app where I am hiding and showing tabbar on an event, below is the method I am using , when I try to hide it, it works fine . But when I am trying to make it visible it doesn't work.

```
-(void)setTabBarVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

  //  RootViewController* tabBarController = (RootViewController*)self.navigationController.parentViewController.parentViewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.tabBarController;

    CGFloat duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;

    CGRect frame = tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat offsetY = (visible)? -height : height;


    CGRect playerFrame = player.view.frame;
    CGRect toolBarFrame = self.toolbar.frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

        CGRect fr = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, offsetY);
        tabBarController.tabBar.frame = fr;
        if((!visible && ![self toolBarOnBottom]) || visible) {
            self.toolbar.frame = CGRectOffset(toolBarFrame, 0, offsetY);
            [self.toolbar layoutIfNeeded];
        }

    } completion:completion];


}
```

I when I debug code the second time I call this method to make it visible , the tabbar frame is zero , I think this is the problem. I am testing this on Xcode 9 with iOS 11 SDK. I am not sure if Safe area has anything to do with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Is by any chance `tabBarController` `nil` ? 2. When do you call this method ? (from what other methods). 3. Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: tabbarcontroller isn't nil , and yes i m using auto layout

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted to get a working solution , ended up using this , works perfect with autolayout and safe area

[Hide UINavBar and UITabBar at the same time with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036961/hide-uinavbar-and-uitabbar-at-the-same-time-with-animation)