# Customer UITabbarController , show and hide When present to a new view?

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, show, hidden

I customized a `UITabbarController` and give 5 `NavigationController` to it, such as:

```
    WXCustomerBar* bar = [[WXCustomerBar alloc]init];   
[bar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[IndexView alloc]init]],  [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[SecondView alloc]init]]
```

In the `indexView`  the tabbar is shown, when I click a button to present another view `settingView` I want to hide the tabbar. Then when I click the button in settingView, present into the SecondView, I want to display the tabbar.

This is my present method:

```
-(void)presentToNetViewController:(id)viewController
{
    if (![viewController isKindOfClass:[WXCustomerBar class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navi = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
        [self presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else
    {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

I'm not English, sorry for my odd language.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has a `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property. Set this to `YES`, and when you do `[self presentViewControlller: viewController animated: YES completion: nil]`, the bar will automatically be hidden until you press the back button.

In addition to this, you are able to tell the UITabBarController itself to hide by doing this:

`[self hideTabBar: self.navigationController.tabBarController];`

You can look at this answer for more: [How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: This property i have try , but unsuccessed , hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is just for uncustomer tabbar

Comment: It works for me. Make sure that the property is set for the view controller, not the tab bar.

Comment: er ,yestertoday ,i try to dismis current viewcontroller when present to next page :

Comment: it just like    self dismisViewcontroller]; tabbar selectIndex:] let tabbarcontroller present the page