# UITabBarController area isn't clickable after hiding

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uiwindow

I have 2 view controllers **VC1** and **VC2**

**VC1** is a `UITableViewController` and upon selection of any row it hides the `UITabBarController`. Then it is pushed to **VC2** (here `UITabBarController` is hidden). Now I added few buttons in the area of `UITabBarController` with some events on them but the problem is they are not clickable. When I move the buttons anywhere on the view they work very fine.

What should I do?

Comment: [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

Comment: Also I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: That question relates only to hiding the tab bar when not pushing a new view controller onto screen. You may want to look at Hack_123's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
    vc2.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

If you dont want to use this code Please let me know the reason.

Comment: Let me try first. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Great! It works very fine. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that your Vc belong to UINavigationController , and that UINavigationController is combined with a UITabBarController. And you have hidden tab bar but you have not increased size of vC in it. so Increase height of your Vc after hiding the tab bar.

also in ViewWillAppear of Your VC do this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated 
{
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this precisely. Much appreciated!