# Make a view between UINavigationBar and UITabBar full screen in landscape on iPhone

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, fullscreen, uitabbar, landscape

I've got a `UITabBarController` containing different `UINavigationControllers`. One of those `UINavigationController`'s `rootViewController` displays a chart (using `ShinobiCharts`) between the `UINavigationBar` and the `UITabBar` in portrait mode. When turning to landscape, I'd like to hide both the `UINavigationBar` and the `UITabBar` and display my chart full screen. Not a problem for the navigation bar, I don't know how to that for the tab bar. I can hide it but resizing the chart after hiding does not make it as big as I want it to be.

This seems to be a pretty straight forward demand and I bet there's a fairly simple solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller/11490623#11490623).

Essentially you change the size of the tab bar view so that the tab bar is outside of the window bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
{
  [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width,            
  view.frame.size.height)];
}
else
{
  [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y,        
  view.frame.size.width, 480)];
}
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
{
  [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width,    
  view.frame.size.height)];

}
else
{
  [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y,  
  view.frame.size.width, 431)];
 }
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The thing here is, simply hiding the `tabBar` is not a solution, since the nested `subviews` will not be resized.

I use the above code when I want to hide the `tabBar` and resize it's `subviews`. You will have to do the hide/show the frames BEFORE you push your `viewController` (with the chart).