# Cannot detect tap after hiding tabbar

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 7. I have a UITableView inside a UITabbarController.

I hide the tabbar using the following code (meanwhile I also set the tableView to be fullscreen)

```
CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
frame.origin.y = 568.0;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = frame;
```

However, after that, I cannot select the cell near the bottom. When tap at the position where the tabbar was, there is no effect.

Has anyone run into the same problem? Do anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Do not change the tab bar's frame. What you're trying to do is not supported by UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490623/1670190) to detect the tab bar and then hide.