# iOS Init Tab Bar Controller View Controllers in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am trying to initalize a view controller, which will be loaded once the Tab Bar controller starts.

For example, initially the `Tab Bar Controller` is not shown, once you log in, the `tab bar controller` is there.

Because the `Tab Bar Controller` isn't loaded when the app is loaded, I can't reference the `View Controllers` inside the `Tab Bar Controller` (to my knowledge). So what I am trying to do is in the `AppDelegate`, create an instance of a `view controller` class, set some properties, and when the `Tab Bar Controller` is loaded, and the `View Controller` is loaded, initialize it with the instance of the class I created in the `AppDelegate`.

Is any of this possible, or is there a better way that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to have your initial [login] view contained within the `UITabBarController`, set the tab bar to hidden ([see this SO post on hiding a tab bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller)), and once logged in show the tab bar. The user will not notice that the login view is contained within a tab bar, and you can set up your other view controllers all within the class that has your `UITabBarController`.