# How to hide tab bar in my custom navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I want to hide bottom tab bar when pushing new view controllers into `UINavigationController` (I'm using default tab bar). I do this by inherit `UINavigationController` and create my custom navigation controller.

I override below two functions:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"NavigationController: View controller count = %lu", self.viewControllers.count);
    if (self.viewControllers.count <= 2) {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

In app delegate:

```
// Use my custom navigation controller
NavigationController *myNav1 = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
myNav1.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
myNav1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"abc" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc"]];

...

self.tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNav1, myNav2, myNav3, myNav4, nil];
```

**Problem:**

1. When pushing new view controllers, the bottom bar will hides immediately, I want it to look like be pushed with view controllers.
2. When I try to return to previous view controller use gestures, the bottom bar will show, even I stop returning, it will not hide.

I know a flag `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. If I use that flag, I need to set it to `YES` every time I need to push a view controller. It is a little complex.

Is there a way to fix these problems in my custom navigation controller?

Comment: u r using default tabbar or custom tabbar ?

Comment: @ravi.p I'm using default tabbar.

Comment: take one UINavigationController object in app delegate and in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions assign it     self.appNavController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController; so when u want to push without tabbar use it with app delegate

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11490623/4831524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems solves my problem (code is not very good, will do some update later):

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"NavigationController.pushViewController: view controller count %lu", self.viewControllers.count);

    UIViewController *lastVC = nil;
    if (self.viewControllers.count > 0) {
        lastVC = self.viewControllers[self.viewControllers.count - 1];
    }
    if (lastVC != nil) {
        lastVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    if (self.viewControllers.count == 2) {
        lastVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    }
}
```