# Hiding tab bar on one view in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

I have a Tab bar application where I would like to hide the tab bar for one of the views to exchange it with a toolbar. I am using Storyboard and by setting the Bottom Bar to None and dragging in a toolbar this looks the way I would want it on the storyboard.
But when I run it the Tab bar doesn't go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wont work because it only simulate the view when the tabbar is hidden. If you want to hide tabbar you have to do it programmatically.

See this answer [Iphone: Is it possible to hide the TabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982172/iphone-is-it-possible-to-hide-the-tabbar)

and try to use hideTabbar method in viewWillAppear, and showTabbar in viewDidDisapear.

Comment: That worked beautifully in portrait. Just have to work out how to get it to work in landscape. Will I have problem between iPhone 5 and 4?

Comment: Following downwards in that link I found the right version that worked great for all sorts of screens and both landscape and portrait. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question but ended up finding my correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296065/ios-tabbarviewcontroller-hide-the-tab-bar)

Essentially, you can hide the tab bar for certain view controller by checking the 'Hide bottom bar on push' check box (in the view controllers attributes inspector in the storyboard).

This might not answer all, and might not be compatible with =< iOS 5, etc, but it helped me and I hope it helps others who come here.

Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: I had a problem with this approach. When the new view appears, the space where the tab bar would be is empty, then the view stretches to occupy that space.